# Writing systems that do not preserve spoken order

Tags: writing-systems

Are there writing systems where there are cases of written form of words not preserving the order of speech, i.e. `text(A)` precedes `text(B)` in the written form, but `speech(B)` precedes `speech(A)`?

Only words written in the native script(s) should be considered: semiotics such as "$10" which is read as "10 dollars" are excluded explicitly.

And of course the distinction between LTR/RTL doesn't matter here, as the ordering here would be defined to be the respsective direction of each writing system.

Comment: Are you really excluding numerals? Are these not part of the "native scripts"?

Comment: @fdb: I think those are mostly trivial?

Comment: I don't know enough to answer your question, but what about systems that are laid out in two dimensions, like hieroglyphics or that ancient Mayan one?

Comment: Numbers are actually the best example for this. So, in German you write 46, but you read it as sechsundvierzig..

Comment: Devanagari long and short /i/ vowels violate the order.

Comment: @fdb Don't know German, but I find it interesting that it seems to be weirder than backwards. Using Google Translate, it seems that with 123, you vocalize the 1 then the 3 then the 2 as einhundertdreiundzwanzig.

Comment: @JoL, that's how it is in German, the tens and ones are "swapped". Of course also in tens of thousands etc., so 1 234 567 reads like "one million, two hundred four-and-thirty thousand, five hundred seven-and-sixty", except with less spacing of course. I can't remember exactly but it seems they just write it all in a row as one word, shudder.

Comment: @JoL rather like dates in American MDY format.  And "four and twenty" was formerly common in English too

Comment: @ChrisH Except those are vocalized the same way they're written. 4/20/2021 is April 20th, 2021.

Comment: @JoL always? In British English we  write DMY, but are more flexible in speech.  Anyway you vocalise out of the logical progression from most precise to least or vice versa, just as with German numbers

Comment: @ChrisH "but are more flexible in speech" -- Yes, one may say "April 20th" or "20th of April", but I assume that's because the language users have 2 date formats that reflect that order. "April 20th" is what I most commonly hear in the US, and I think that's because it's more natural to vocalize that when reading MDY dates.

Comment: I'm surprised no-one's mentioned **currency** yet.  ‘£42’ is read as “forty-two pounds”, not “pounds forty-two”.  (In fact, I've occasionally seen a currency sign put _after_ the numerals — though whether that's for consistency with speech, or with non-currency units such as length and speed, I'm not sure.  Either way, I think I prefer it :)

Comment: I''ve heard this is true of Chinese. Can somebody check?

Comment: @gidds: the OP mentioned currency in the second paragraph.

Comment: @ilkkachu, according to one source, it is “eine Million zweihundertvierunddreißigtausendfünfhundertsiebenundsechzig“. Seems right to me.

Comment: @fdb Of course, while 46 is written LTR, the written symbol is parsed RTL :)

Answer (score 23):

**Hieroglyphic Egyptian** has a feature called "honorific transposition", where certain nouns can be written at the beginning of a noun phrase (regardless of their actual syntactic position) if they're more important than all the other nouns.

For example, one type of priest is called a *ħm-nṯr*, "servant of the god". Grammatically, in this construction, the "owner" noun (nomen regens) needs to come second, and its Coptic descendant is *hont*. But since "god" is clearly more important than "servant", it's written orthographically as *nṯr-ħm*.

This mostly only happens with words relating to deities ("god", "pharaoh", names of gods, etc), but during certain periods it was also common to transpose a father's name in front of a child's name. The scribe who wrote the best-surviving copy of the Shipwrecked Sailor, for example, recorded his name as *jmny zꜣ jmnꜥꜣ*, literally "Amoni, son of Amona'a" ("owner" noun coming second as above). But depending on the time period, this could instead be read as *jmnꜥꜣ zꜣ jmny*, "Amona'a, son of Amoni". Google says the papyrus is from the 12th dynasty, so I think it's the latter; transposing the father's name was common in that era.

There were also sometimes "aesthetic transpositions", where the graphemes were rearranged for purely aesthetic reasons. Variant spellings of the word for "in front of" demonstrate that it should be pronounced *ḫft*. However, the glyphs for *ḫ* and *t* are small, and *f* is long and flat, so arranging them in this order tends not to look good. Instead, it's most commonly written *ḫtf*, so that the two small signs can be arranged over the flat one.

Answer (score 17):

There is a whole class of languages that use [Abugida writing system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abugida) which shows this phenomenon on a regular basis. Most prominent examples are **Hindi and Thai**.

Using Thai writing for examples below.

No final (CV):

- เ◌ + ม = เม `/e+m/ = /me/`
- โ◌ + ม = โม `/o+m/ = /mo/`
- ไ◌ + ม = ไม `/ai+m/ = /mai/`

With Final (CVC):

- เ◌ + ม + ม = เมม `/e+m+m/ = /mem/`
- โ◌ + ม + ม = โมม `/o+m+m/ = /mom/`

Di- and triphthongs are pronounced in order different to the order of character appearance:

- เ◌ + ต + ◌ี + ย + ง = เตียง (bed) `/e+t+ii+j+ng/ = /tiang/`

A more complex example demonstrating epenthesis (svarabhakti):

- เ◌ + ส + ม + อ = เสมอ (forever) `/e+s+m+_/ = /sa-mer/`
- เ◌ + ฉ + ล + ◌ี + ย + ง = เฉลียง (corridor; hall) `/e+ch+l+ii+j+ng/ = /cha-liang/` (compare to the เตียง example above).

Comment: How come `<e+tᵃ+ii+jᵃ+ng>` gives _ti*e*ng_, but in the seemingly entirely parallel (leaving out the `<ch>`) case of `<e+lᵃ+ii+jᵃ+ng>` the result is _li*a*ng_?

Comment: the vowel is usually considered a diacritic here, rather than an independent glyph, so this is a kind-of borderline case as to whether it counts

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, thanks, corrected.

Comment: I thought the OP was asking about word order, not grapheme order. Conceptually, /ka/ and /ke/ are different letters, even though they're clearly related and there are rules about how to derive one from the other. The vowel strokes are not thought of as independent from the consonant they attach to, much like the dot of an "i" or "j" is not thought of as a separate part. If you're going with letter order, there are English words like "what". When the /h/ is pronounced, it is "hwat", and that's how it was originally written, such as the first word of the epic poem "Beowulf".

Comment: @CJDennis It can probably be argued that _what_ contains /hw/, but it’s more economical to treat it as a single phoneme /ʍ/, written with a digraph, parallel to /θ/ <th>. /h/ does not otherwise appear syllable-initially before consonants, the only exception being the sequence /ju/, which behaves differently to sequences of /w/ + vowel – as indicated also by the fact that /ʍ/ can also appear before /ju/, as in _whew_ /ʍjuː/, while a sequence /hwj/ would be entirely unparallelled.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet "Whew" is also pronounced /fjuː/ and spelt "phew".

Comment: @CJDennis Those are separate words, at least to me.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I have no idea how to pronounce "whew" without an /f/. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/whew

Comment: @CJDennis Then they clearly differ for us. I’d pronounce it [ʍĭ̥ŭ̥] (as indicated on Wiktionary) in most cases as a natural exclamation of relief, but /fjuː/ or /pjuː/ if being deliberately sarcastic.

Answer (score 15):

German numbers.

42 is read as "Zweiundvierzig", literally "Two and Forty".
This order swap only happens for numbers between 20-100.

Comment: It starts at 13 = dreizehn = "three ten"

Comment: @knabar Actually, many languages do the same thing with "teens" -> Thirteen, not "Ten-Three". Which is pretty odd, when you look at it, but explainable as simply extending the first ten into second ten (assuming people rarely had reason to count past that)

Comment: @RonJohn French numbers are pronounced in the same order as English.

Comment: @asac you're right.  I was thinking of "80", which is "four 20" in French.  Odd, but a different rule.

Comment: This also exists in Danish where 77 is read as "syv-og-halvfjerds" (seven and half [before] four [twenties]). To some extent this is also used in Norwegian, probably because of Danish influences from when Norway belonged to Denmark.

Comment: @md2perpe the Danish number system is not used in Norwegian (it's in fact one of the things that Norwegians like to ridicule as utterly incomprehensible about the Danes). The standard Norwegian system is now basically the same as in English (77 = syttisju ≈ seventy·seven), though many people still use the _German_ system (77 = syvogsytti ≈ seven·and·seventy), which was standard in Riksmål writing – Riksmål being indeed mostly Danish, but I doubt the number order came from Danish.

Comment: @leftaroundabout. I was thinking about the German system, but realize that I wasn't clear and that it looked like I meant things like "halvfjerds". Thanks for you clarification.

Answer (score 10):

**Sumerian cuneiform** has certain fossilized transpositions, where a sequence of signs got re-analyzed as a single logogram and then did not change when the syntax of the language changed.

For example, it seems that adjectives used to precede the nouns they modify in Sumerian, but this order became archaic and eventually died out by the Ur III period: earlier *gal-niŋir* "chief herald", later *niŋir-gal*. But a few of these early compounds fossilized in writing, and later *lú-gal* "king" remained written GAL.LÚ. (Likewise *ušum-gal* "dragon" remains written GAL.UŠUM.) We know that the pronunciations were *lú-gal* and *ušum-gal* based on Akkadian glosses and phonological properties ("of the king" is written GAL.LÚ-*la*, for example, showing that the stem ends with an L), but the "inverted" spellings survived into Akkadian and Hittite, where the native words for "king" are still written with the logogram GAL.LÚ.

Answer (score 9):

Japanese was once written as Chinese, with markers to indicate how the characters should be reorganised to Japanese grammar.  This style of writing is called kanbun. The Chinese characters are written as they would be in China, with numerals and other markers written between them to indicate the order in which they should be read.

Comment: @jogloran James K is referring to Kanbun, a system of marking Classical Chinese text so that it can be read aloud in Japanese, which tends to put verbs last. See [Wikipedia's 楚人有鬻盾與矛者 example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanbun#Example).

Comment: @Janus: if you check the edit history, the responder has just completely changed the topic of their post, which is a little rude. It used contain an inaccurate claim about Cantonese.

Comment: @jogloran Ah, I see! I wondered how Cantonese entered into this at all, but didn’t notice the edit that deleted that part of the answer.

Comment: Actually, I realised that this answer is still incorrect — is it really true that "Japanese was once written as Chinese"? I would say no. Kanbun is a completely separate style to Japanese prose. The source text in Kanbun is Chinese, through and through.

Comment: The source is Japanese, as there are indications on reading which indicate that a Japanse reading is intended for some characters.  The order of the characters is Chinese, and doesn't match the reading order, so markers are added to indicate the reading order. When read, you read according to the indicated order, not the page order.  The underlying language is Japanese.

Comment: Huh? The underlying language is Middle Chinese — that's why kanbun is necessary in the first place. Kanbun is a way to contort the original text so that it minimally satisfies Japanese syntax, but it's not Japanese.

Comment: Readrs thought they were reading Chinese, but often they were reading it as neither Chinese nor Japanese, but a weird mixture.

Answer (score 9):

English (in particular British English) does this more or less systematically, when a final *e* is preceded by certain consonant combinations.
The *e* appears in pronunciation before the consonant or changes the pronunciation of vowels before the consonant:

- *apple* → /æpəl/
- *subtle* → /sʌtəl/
- *centre* → /sentəɹ/
- *gape* → /ɡeɪp/ (contrast with *gap*)

Comment: I don't think *gape* is an example of this, as it's part of a pattern of a silent e after a consonant elongating the vowel before it (which, due to the great vowel shift, is no longer a long /a/ but a diphthong /ei/).

Comment: @Hearth: Hmm, half a sentence got lost there. Please see my edit. Anyway, the *e* has a backwards effect on pronunciation, whether it appears itself or not. I will leave it to the asker whether it is what they are looking for.

Comment: That e is silent. `pl`, `tl`, etc. are in fact final syllables with no vowels. If you're inserting a schwa between the letters you're pronouncing it wrong.

Comment: @Joshua What do you mean by "wrong"? Aren't there dialects that do that? Or are you saying they should be analyzed as syllabic consonants? [l̩]

Comment: @wjandrea: Indeed they are syllabic consonants. I am aware of that concept but hadn't known the name before. If you find me a dialect that pronounces that e but doesn't have a keep-vowel artifact (that is, where a vowel keeps on being pronounced between words all the time) I'll gladly retract my "wrong" but I haven't heard one yet.

Comment: @Joshua I pronounce syllabic /l̩/ vocalically ([ˈʔæpʰu], [ˈsɐtˢu] etc.), but other syllabic consonants have a clear schwa: *button* [ˈbɐɾən], *prism* [ˈpʰɻʷʏzəm].

Comment: @bradrn: Neither of which are `tl`, `bl`; etc. (usually at the end of a word but there are some exceptions).

Comment: @Joshua I’m not quite sure why this is relevant. You said that English syllabic consonants have no schwa; I supplied examples of my pronunciation which has a schwa.

Comment: @bradrn: Rather some of them.

Comment: @Joshua: Can you really reasonably draw a line between, e.g., /æpəl/ and /æpl̩/? The only way I can pronounce *apple* without a hint of a schwa requires major mouth acrobatics that I have never seen in real speech. (Might be worth asking a question on this, if it doesn’t exist yet …)

Comment: @ˈvʀ̩ʦl̩ˌpʀm̩ft really? I'd say in “apple”, the tongue is in contact already in the “p”, and it never leaves again – i.e., it really is ['æpl]. Perhaps in southern US it's stretched to an actual schwa? Many BE speakers would in fact rather utter only something like ['apʰ], with no actual “l” or “e” sound at all, as bradm said.

Comment: @ˈvʀ̩ʦl̩ˌpʀm̩ft I can. English phonotactics allows /æpəl/, but doesn't allow /æpl̩/ as a complete utterance. Admittedly it does allow it as part of one, e.g. /,æpl̩ɪ'keiʃən/. but there the /l/ is in the next syllable's onset. French allows such clusters in syllable codas -- *simple*, par exemple -- but English doesn't.

Comment: @leftaroundabout A claim that a syllable of an English word contains no vowel is not a matter of how exactly the tongue moves but rather a matter of how people choose to analyse the utterance by chopping it up into phonemes. English doesn't do vowelless syllables. How do you pronounce the second vowel of "prison" (the one spelt "o")? No vowel at all? Then how do you indicate that the last syllable of "prison" is like that of "Susan" but unlike that of "resin"?

Comment: For an example in English that does not involve silent letters, consider former NFL quarterback Brett Favre, where "r" and "v" are both but in the opposite order in which they appear in writing.

Answer (score 4):

**Hebrew** consists of syllables, with a vowel (which may be silent) after each consonant (which may also be silent). A reversal happens in the case of a *p**a**sach* (approximately as English *f**a**r*) when combined with one of the  guttural consonants, *aleph* (which is silent), *mappiq* (pronounced) ***h**ey*, ***ch**es* (as in Scottish *lo**ch***), or ***ʿ**ayin* (⟨ʕ⟩), at the very end of a word. There, the consonant-vowel combination is pronounced in reverse.

For example is the Biblical name *Noah* which more correctly would be spelled *Noach* since the final consonant is ***ch**es*. The Hebrew literally spells out *No-**cha***, but the pronunciation of the ***ch**es-with-p**a**sach* cluster is reversed to ***ach***.

Comment: Note that Adam's transliteration is in the Ashkenazi tradition, which matches neither that of European Hebraicists (who would write _paṯaḥ_) or Modern Hebrew speakers, who write _pataḥ_ or _patach_, and pronounce the middle consonant as /t/. Similarly for _ches_.

Comment: But also not that the specific pronunciation is irrelevant for the described phenomenon; everyone agrees about this reversal.

Answer (score 3):

As you have discovered from the answers, writing systems do not exactly submit to a strict ordering of elements. In Devanagari writing, elements can overlap: there are "ligatures", many of which are illustrated on [this page](https://app.memrise.com/course/231917/sanskrit-devanagari/8/). For example, the consonant elements of the ligature *kva*, *kla* and in general *rCa* for any consonant overlap in left-to-right order. Vowel in Devanagari are mixed, but none of them strictly precede or strictly follow, they all overlap the consonant to some extent (pi=पि, pi:=पी). A few "mostly" follow or "mostly" precede (when they have a "stick"), but the general pattern is that vowels overlap the consonant mark (pu=पु). The "exception" is that certain long vowels have a stick that hosts the vowel marker, so that the mark for "a:" entirely follows the consonant (pa:=पा) since short a doesn't have a vowel mark. Thus in pe:=पे there is (mostly) overlap because the mark for "e" doesn't sit on a stick, but in po:=पो, there is just "some overlap" with *p*, because the mark (basically the same thing as the mark for "e") is on a stick.

[Korean Hangul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangul) likewise does not easily submit to a strict left-right ordering analysis: instead, each syllable is a "box" and you position the consonants and vowels depending on whether the element is onset, nucleus or coda. The coda is "below", so it overlaps the onset and nucleus.

Comment: It's not as simple as LTR or such, but there is a specific, predictable ordering of the jamo within each hangeul square, like there is for the glyphs within an Egyptian quadrat.

Answer (score 2):

Some numbers in English (and some numbers of other European languages)

13 is Thirteen, literally meaning Three and Ten. Though the example is not as nice as @Thomas' example for German.

This is not unique to English. In Italian we have:

13 is tredici, literally meaning Three (tre) and Ten (dieci), as well.

Answer (score 1):

In the [Devanagari script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devanagari#Vowel_diacritics), the sign for a short i precedes the consonant it follow in the spoken language, the syllable ki is written कि, while the syllable kī with long i is written की. Of course you can interpret this in different ways (e.g., as a diacritic) but the fact remains that at least on a Devanagi typewriter, the short i is produced before the consonant.

Answer (score 1):

1. Tones (e.g. in Chinese) are often indicated by a symbol after the syllable, but the tone apples to the preceding nucleus. This is especially visible in  [Wade–Giles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wade%E2%80%93Giles), where the tone is a superscript number (syllable-final consonants are rare in Mandarin, but there are some), e.g. Wei¹ Chai² Shih⁴
   P'in¹-yin¹.
2. Many languages change the pitch to indicate questions, this is marked in writing by a [question mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Question_mark) placed *after* the clause (Spanish and Armenian being two major exceptions).